# jquery how to show-hide table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I hide a entire table column with jQuery?

I managed to hide a single `td`, but not the other 2 `td`s under it. Code to hide table `td`:

```
$("#td_maand").hide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily:

```
var i = [your_column_index];
$('td:nth-child(' + i + ')').hide();​
```

Comment: I just want to point out that this will effect all tables present.

Answer (score 3):

Give all the same column tds the same class, then `$(".columnClass").hide();`

e.g.

```
<tr><td class="firstcolumn"></td><td class="secondcolumn"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="firstcolumn"></td><td class="secondcolumn"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="firstcolumn"></td><td class="secondcolumn"></td></tr>
<script>$(".firstcolumn").hide();</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**nth-child**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector to achieve that, use it like this:

```
$('#yourtable tr td:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

that will hide your third column.

Comment: IMHO This is the cleanest answer since it does not require classing your cells.

Comment: just gonna add that when you have several hide/show options in your table, this is going to get real messy. If you change anything in the table layout, same deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(this) // assuming this points to a td
  .closest('tbody') // find closest tbody (container)
  .find('> tr > td:nth-child('+$(this).index()+')') // find all td in the same column
  .hide(); // hide them
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jFv6d/
(*it hides the clicked column*)

Answer (score 0):

try `$("#td_maand").parent().hide();`

Comment: Wouldn't that hide the entire ROW (not COLUMN) since that would be the parent of what I presume is a `<td>`?